Python script failing to connect to Azure SQL Database
I get to the https://login.microsoftonline.com/ page and I get a "Authentication complete. You can close this window." message. I'm running the following script. I can't figure out if there's something wrong with the script. On the other side, my IP is already added. My user has admin.
Anyway, find any problems?
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential

#Azure SQL Database connection parameters
server = 'conosur.database.windows.net'
database = 'legacy (conosur/legacy)'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

#Set up the Azure AD credential
credential = InteractiveBrowserCredential()

#Obtain an Azure AD token
token = credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/.default')

#Create the connection string with the token
connection_string = (
f'DRIVER={driver};'
f'SERVER={server};'
f'DATABASE={database};'
f'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryAccessToken;'  # Correct Authentication parameter
f'ACCESS_TOKEN={token.token}'  # Correctly set the access token
)

try:
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
print("Connection established successfully")
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
sqlstate = ex.args\[0\]
print(f"Error connecting to SQL Server: {sqlstate}")
print(f"Detailed error: {ex}")
exit()

#Define query
query = 'SELECT \* FROM your_table_name'
try:
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
print("DataFrame created successfully")
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error executing query: {e}")
finally:
connection.close()  # Ensure the connection is closed

#Display the DataFrame
print(df.head())

Error message:
Error connecting to SQL Server: 08001 Detailed error: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Authentication' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
I'm hoping to log in with my Entra ID in the prompted window. But after doing it, I get the error message above.

Not sure of what is causing it  but it may be the ODBC driver because the parameter you are trying to add to your connection string:  Authentication  is not valid.  Either the parameter is incorrect/different or not supported in the version of the driver you are using.

Switched to ODBC 18 and changed the syntaxis according. Got in!! Thanks
In case anybody ends up here:
conn_str = (
f"DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};"
f"SERVER={DATABASE_SERVER};"
f"DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};"
f"AUTHENTICATION=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;"
)

For other people landing here in the future... neither pyodbc nor ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server support the connection string keywords and attributes that op was using in their posted question. To do this using pyodbc and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server see peoples' various attempts at accessToken support? #228 and have a read through Authenticating with an access token (and the rest of the page) to understand why.


Detailed error: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'Authentication' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

You have provided ActiveDirectoryAccessToken for Authentication parameter in connection string, it is invalid that may be the reason forgetting above error. To fix this, you should use the ActiveDirectoryInteractive authentication method, which is designed for scenarios where the user must manually authenticate (e.g., through a browser popup). You can use below code to connect azure SQL database:
import pyodbc

server = '<serverName>.database.windows.net'
database = '<dbName>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
connection_string = (
f'DRIVER={driver};'
f'SERVER={server};'
f'DATABASE={database};'
f'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;' 
)
try:
  connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
  print("Connection established successfully")
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
  print(f"Detailed error: {ex}")

It will give a pop-up window for authentication, after successful authentication you will be able connect SQL database successfully as shown below:

